# Redirect subdirectory to other directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm newbie in apache, i have the following directory structure:

```
html
|-- moodle
    |-- singapur
        |-- app
        |-- public
           |-- js
           |-- css
           |-- img
           |-- index.php
```

I need redirect from `www.mywebpage.com/singapur` to `www.mywebpage.com/singapur/public`

the `.htaccess` located in the folder `singapur` is:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(/.+)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the `.htaccess` located in the folder `public` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /singapur/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `public/` folder also have a .htaccess?

Comment: It seems you're not looking for an HTTP redirection, but for a **URL rewrite**

Comment: @anubhava i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Make `.htaccess` located in the folder `singapur` is:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /singapur/

    RewriteRule .* public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Keep your `singapur/public/.htaccess` unchanged.

Comment: don't work `You don't have permission to access /singapur/ on this server.`

Comment: That is some permission issue not related to these rules. Rename this .htacces to something else and then visit `www.mywebpage.com/singapur/`